# Rails jobs stuck for sidekiq error broken pipeline using mqtt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, mqtt, sidekiq

I've an error when Sidekiq trying to process a Rails Job.
I'm now migrating the web app to google cloud service where i set up a redis server and the broker mqtt.

The Active Job is the following:

```
 def publish_update
topic = "tournament_team_category/#{@round_match.round.tournament_team_category.id}"
payload = {
  round_match: {
    id: @round_match.id,
    started_at: @round_match.started_at,
    ended_at: @round_match.ended_at,
    first_round_match_team: {
      id: @round_match.first_round_match_team.id,
      goals: @round_match.first_round_match_team.goals
    },
    second_round_match_team: {
      id: @round_match.second_round_match_team.id,
      goals: @round_match.second_round_match_team.goals
    }
  }
}

# TODO: Improve exception manage
begin
  MQTT_CLIENT.connect
  MQTT_CLIENT.publish(topic, payload.to_json, false, 1)
  MQTT_CLIENT.disconnect
rescue MQTT::NotConnectedException => _e
  return nil
rescue MQTT::ProtocolException => _e
  return nil
end
end
```

When Sidekiq try to execute this job the server show me this error:

```
2020-10-01 13:22:39 worker[20201001t140958]  2020-10-01T13:22:39.897Z 1 TID-gtixo1hip WARN: Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe
2020-10-01 13:22:39 worker[20201001t140958]  2020-10-01T13:22:39.897Z 1 TID-gtixo1hip WARN: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mqtt-0.5.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:556:in `write'
2020-10-01 13:22:39 worker[20201001t140958]  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mqtt-0.5.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:556:in `block in send_packet'
```

The mqtt client.rb line 556 code is:

```
# Send a packet to server
   def send_packet(data)
# Raise exception if we aren't connected
   raise MQTT::NotConnectedException if not connected?

# Only allow one thread to write to socket at a time
   @write_semaphore.synchronize do
   @socket.write(data.to_s)
 end
end
```

I can't find any solution to fix this and my jobs still in stuck.
Anyone ever had this kind of problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your MQTT client usage isn't threadsafe, you need this:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#connection-pooling

Comment: Thank, i'm not really skilled with sidekiq advanced options. As i understood i have to generate a separate worker for sidekiq right? 
Can you help me to set it with my code please?